# Multiple Collapsable Sections with non-collapsable sections divided by headers

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview, sections

So I have been scouring the internet but can't find the solution. Currently I have a tableview with collapsable sections, the rows within these sections are off course related to the section. I have two other categories that don't need these collapsable sections, these are just rows. Currently I have a segment control that has the following:

- Category 1 (Collapsable sections with each a different number of rows)
- Category 2 (Standard list of rows)
- Category 3 (Standard list of rows)
- Category 4 (all of the above)

Category 1-3 work fine. But I can't combine all in one view. I would like to have three headers with each showing their corresponding category. First header should show all sections that are collapsable. The other two just rows.

What I tried:

- Using section count to give each category a header but this ends if giving a header to all sections individually.
- Using section count to give each category a view.
- Potentially, creating three TableViews for each category if all Segment is selected.

Can anyone help in the right direction to what would be the best solutution.

I don't think my code will help because I'm still not sure what method I should use.

I did make a drawing to show what I mean:

[image: Category 1 for example has 3 sections with 2 expanded, this works fine individually]

if anyone has an idea that would be fantastic, thanks!

Comment: You could build your table view with a json, where category headers are the sections of the table view, each section could have an attribute  "children" as an array of rows, then these rows could also have an attribute "children" as an array.

After all this, when a collapsable section is tapped you could append rows under that subsection using the index of the subsection tapped, when tapped again, you could remove the rows, changes should be inside tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates().

Comment: @JavierHeisecke Currently I'm using Coredata to store some calculated variables. With these variables I then request data from the API and update my tableview. I should create a json with this data and from there update the tableview? The tableview will have to be updated every 2 seconds so it is quite intensive. I haven't encoded into a json so I will look into your suggestion. Thanks for the tip Javier.

Comment: you could map it to json like structures